# Clicking notification take me to generic feed rather than to chat section

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

When I receive a notification In Teams from *Bot A* and I click on the popup the system does not navigate to the *Bot A* chat section, but to the generic Feed.

[image]

> clicking on this take me to generic feed i.e

[image]

Comment: We will also check it from our end and let you know.

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same. The engineering team is looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

We got an update from the engineering team, this is expected behavior. The left side panel will just stay at "Feed", which is by design.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to bypass this "design" ?

Comment: No, there is no way